# How to keep asking location permission as long as the status is not granted-Flutter

Tags: flutter, permissions, location, permission-denied

I am trying to ask location permission of user in my project apps, so after user denied the permission I would like to keep showing pop up to ask location permission whenever user try to access a menu. I success to do that by using this function

```
trial() async {
    await Permission.locationAlways.request();
    print(Permission.locationAlways.status.then((value) {
      print("value:$value");
    }));
  }
```

but the problem is.. after the status is `PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied` the pop up to ask location permission is stop showing. Is there a way to always ask permission as long as the permission is not granted or a way to open up setting of location permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to below code

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color(0xfff00B074),
        textTheme: const TextTheme(
          bodyText1: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18.0,
              fontFamily: 'Barlow-Medium',
              color: Color(0xff464255)),
        ),
      ),
      home: PermissionHandlerScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class PermissionHandlerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PermissionHandlerScreenState createState() =>
      _PermissionHandlerScreenState();
}

class _PermissionHandlerScreenState extends State<PermissionHandlerScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    permissionServiceCall();
  }

  permissionServiceCall() async {
    await permissionServices().then(
      (value) {
        if (value != null) {
          if (value[Permission.location].isGranted ) {
            /* ========= New Screen Added  ============= */

            Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SplashScreen()),
            );
          }
        }
      },
    );
  }

  /*Permission services*/
  Future<Map<Permission, PermissionStatus>> permissionServices() async {
    // You can request multiple permissions at once.
    Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
      Permission.location,
     
      //add more permission to request here.
    ].request();

    if (statuses[Permission.location].isPermanentlyDenied) {
      await openAppSettings().then(
        (value) async {
          if (value) {
            if (await Permission.location.status.isPermanentlyDenied == true &&
                await Permission.location.status.isGranted == false) {
              // openAppSettings();
              permissionServiceCall(); /* opens app settings until permission is granted */
            }
          }
        },
      );
    } else {
      if (statuses[Permission.location].isDenied) {
        permissionServiceCall();
      }
    }
    
    /*{Permission.camera: PermissionStatus.granted, Permission.storage: PermissionStatus.granted}*/
    return statuses;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    permissionServiceCall();
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        SystemNavigator.pop();
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  permissionServiceCall();
                },
                child: Text("Click here to enable Enable Permission Screen")),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        SystemNavigator.pop();
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text(
            "Splash Screen",
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Which packages are you importing? This code doesnt run in 2024.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `permission_handler 8.3.0`  package.

and use as:

```
if (await Permission.locationAlways.request().isGranted) {
print(Permission.locationAlways.status.then((value) {
  print("value:$value");
}));
}
```

more details on: [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler)

implementation on: [implementation on](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNklvY1FEao)

Comment: Hi, sorry for my mistake.. in my question before I say that I use location package, after I do re-check it was permission package. I have tried your code, and I still get the same result. The status ```value:PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied``` and the pop up for asking a permission is not showing

Comment: try as using the implementation on...

Comment: I have seen it, and I get it.. Thank you very much for your help :D That helps me